# mysql query to get results from 2 tables by adding sum according to date

Tags: php, mysql

I have query like this, I am able to get data of both the tables individually. The concept is that I want sum of amount according to group by month . From any one table I can retrieve amount correctly, but I have to get sum of amounts from both the tables combined depending on the month.

```
(select SUM(amount) as amount
     , month(reciept_date) as month
     , year(reciept_date) as year 
 from sg_chool 
 where academic_year = '2' 
 group by MONTH(reciept_date)) 

UNION ALL 

(select SUM(amount_paid) as amount
      , month(reciept_date) as month
      , year(reciept_date) as year 
 from sg_fees 
 where academic_year = '2' 
 group by MONTH(reciept_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT sum(temp.amount) as amount, temp.month, temp.year
FROM (
(select SUM(amount) as amount
     , month(reciept_date) as month
     , year(reciept_date) as year 
 from sg_chool 
 where academic_year = '2' 
 group by MONTH(reciept_date)) 

UNION ALL 

  (select SUM(amount_paid) as amount
      , month(reciept_date) as month
      , year(reciept_date) as year 
 from sg_fees 
 where academic_year = '2' 
 group by MONTH(reciept_date))
 ) as temp
GROUP BY temp.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your needs:

```sql
SELECT
  (school.amount + fees.amount) AS amount
    , school.month
    , school.year
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount
    , month(reciept_date) AS month
    , year(reciept_date) AS year 
   FROM sg_chool 
   WHERE academic_year = '2' 
   GROUP BY MONTH(reciept_date)) AS school
JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(amount_paid) AS amount
    , month(reciept_date) AS month
   FROM sg_fees 
   WHERE academic_year = '2'
   GROUP BY MONTH(reciept_date)) AS fees
USING (month)
```

You can try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f043c/4).